# Ember: Mocking RecordArray

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-testing

For acceptance tests of components that involve `peekAll`, I've stubbed the `store` service with the `peekAll` method that returns an array of `Ember.Object`, by which I'm able to retrieve the records and display.

But `save`, `set` and `get` methods aren't working, as `peekAll` in it's original form returns a `RecordArray`.

How do I return a `RecordArray` from the store stub?

Comment: I think it would help if you were to post some more of your code. With a bit more detail, it will be easier to provide you with a specific answer and your question will be more helpful for anyone who encounters this later.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mocking the store service, it might be preferable to inject it, and then use `createRecord` to add your test record to the store. Then the `peekAll` will get a `RecordArray` as per usual, which will include all of the appropriate methods. Otherwise you end up going down a bit of a rabbithole creating more and more mock functions (for example, you could create `save`, `set` and `get` methods, and add them to your EmberObject, but what about the next function you need...).